# How does a syscall knows where the wrapper function put its parameters in?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I'm trying to implement a syscall in Linux (RedHat Enterprise 8) and I'm a bit confused about the way it works. From what I understand, I implement a wrapper in user mode which puts the syscall number in eax and parameters in ebx, ecx, edx, etc, and then invokes int 0x80 which calls the appropriate syscall. My question is, since a syscall is written like a regular C function, how does it know what registers contain what parameters? Is it a convention, or is there a mechanism for it, and if so where and how does it do it?

EDIT: This is a homework assignment. I know that there are syscall macros that can do this stuff for me.

Comment: So why don't you read the macros to see what it is that they're doing?

Comment: I did, but I wasn't able to figure anything out of it. It's not exactly standard assembly code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4048) article, bottom of page 2

> Since the system call interface is exclusively register-parametered, six parameters at most can be used with a single system call. %eax is the syscall number; %ebx, %ecx, %edx, %esi, %edi and %ebp are the six generic registers used as param0-5; and %esp cannot be used because it's overwritten by the kernel when it enters ring 0 (i.e., kernel mode).

Your c code may look like it's making a system call, but it actually calls a function in libc. That function makes sure that all the arguments are in the right registers, and then does the interrupt.